# When to use `this` when defining variables in a function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

From what I've read so far, we can use a function to create an object with "private"/"public" members in javascript. Something along:

```
function foo(param1) {
    this.publicVar= param1;
    privateVar = "can't touch this";

    this.MC = function(){
        var ret = privateVar + ", " + this.publicVar; 
        return ret;
    };
}
```

when called with `var f = new foo("hammer time");` , I would be able to use `f.publicVar` & `f.MC()` , but I'll have no way to touch the `privateVar`.

As you can see in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OyAlUTu/1/edit?html,js,console), all seems to work.

What I don't get is the use of `this` in this case.
Using `this.privateVar` will be undefined, and using `publicVar` without `this` will be undefined.

Here's a more elaborate example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC6aV/).
Having 2 options to create objects, and calling them respectedly:

```
function Option1(aX,aY) {
    var x,y;

    x = aX || 0;    // `||` serves as guard, in case parameters
    y = aY || 0;    // are not defined, initializes to 0;

this.toString = function() {
        var retStr =  "from Option 1: I am here: <br/>"+
        "x: " + x + "<br/>" +           // 1
        "y: " + y + "<br/>" +           // 1 
        "this.x: " + this.x + "<br/>" + // undefined
        "this.y: " + this.y + "<br/>" + // undefined
        "aX: " + aX + "<br/>" +         // 1
        "aY: " + aY ;                   // 1
        return retStr;
    };
    // `this` is returned implicitly 
}

// first has only toString() as "public" member
var first = new Option1(1,1);
```

**Question 1**:
Inside the `toString`, `x` & `y` appear inside the `closure` in the `scope variables` in chrome debugger, but are not reachable with `this`.

```
function Option2(aX,aY) {
    var x,y;

    this.x = aX || 0;
    this.y = aY || 0;

    this.toString = function() {
        var retStr =  "from Option 2: I am here: <br/>"+
        "x: " + x + "<br/>" +           // undefined
        "y: " + y + "<br/>" +           // undefined
        "this.x: " + this.x + "<br/>" + // 22
        "this.y: " + this.y + "<br/>" + // 22
        "aX: " + aX + "<br/>" +         // 22
        "aY: " + aY  ;                  // 22
        return retStr;
    };

}

// second has x,y & toString() as "public" members
var second = new Option2(22,22);
```

**Question 2**:
Inside this `toString`, `x` & `y` **DO NOT** appear inside the `closure` in the `scope variables` in chrome debugger, and are only reachable with `this`.

I would have expected in `Option2` to be able to access `x`, since it'll inherit it from the outer function, but it's not possible without the `this`.

Any clarifications will be highly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: You can access private variables through 'Privileged Methods'.(From Douglas Crockford)

Comment: What are the questions?

Comment: MDN has a pretty extensive overview: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: in `Option1`, why can't i use `this.x`, and in `Option2` why can't i use `x` ?

Comment: I see this more as a Chrome dev tools issue (or its misusage), your concepts are fine.

Comment: In Option 2, `x` and `y` both are accessible. They turned up `undefined` because you haven't assigned them values. Unassigned variables are assigned the value `undefined`. If they weren't accessible, you would have got a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @c.P.u1 argh ... so i could actually remove the `var x,y;` from `Option2`, since it's unneeded rubbish, and probably just confuses me with my c# background ... ?

Comment: Read "JavaScript The Good Parts" for the ultimate explanation (the book is really short, so that's the best way to get the answers to your questions IMHO).

Comment: If you remove `var x,y;` x and y will be global variables. Try in the console `x=true; window.x`and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what happens better now, thanks to **c.P.u1** & **daguru**.
**siledh**: I guess I'll to start reading that book very soon.

Here's an updated - - > [**jsbin link**](http://jsbin.com/OboGacA/3/edit?js,console) < - - that might shed more light on it.

Coming from C# lately, I'm used to defining my variables in functions, so in the above `Option2`, the reason why `x` and `y` are undefined, is because I've defined them as private variables.

If I wouldn't have done that, an exception would have been thrown if I tried to use them without `this`, since the variable wouldn't exist (resulting in `x is not defined`).

Having `x` and `y` as globals, will kinda hide the problem, since it'll will just say `x is undefined` or fall back to it's global values, which unless you understand, or have specific values, might just cause more confusion.

**Recap:**  Calling variables and results:

1. For "private" variables in a function (defined with `var privateVar = something;`)

   - from inside the method

     - calling with `privateVar` -> gives you the local variable, or throws an error if not defined (local NOR global)
     - calling with `this.privateVar` -> returns `undefine` (because it creates one on the object?)
   - `privateVar` is **NOT** accessible from outside the method
2. For "public" variables in a function (defined with `this.publicVar = something;`)

   - from inside the method

     - calling with `this.publicVar` -> gives you the local variable as (if) defined
     - calling with `publicVar` -> throws a ReferenceError (unless you have defined a private var with that name in the function, or you have a global variable with that name, in which case, you'll get that variable.)
       Note: This is extremely silly, yet it happens, as my question proves.
   - `publicVar` is accessible from outside the method (using the object)

Hope this helps someone and save them some hairs on their head :)

Answer (score 0):

In option 1 (I will make the example with only one variable)

```
function Option1(aX) {
    var x; //defining x variable with a certain memory adress   
    x = aX || 0; //assigning to it a value

    //in this case "this.x" doesn't exist   

}
```

In option 2 :

```
function Option2(aX) {
    var x;//defining x variable with a certain memory adress

    this.x = aX || 0; //defining another variable with different memory address and
                      //assign to it the value of the passing parameter


   //in this case this.x != x

}
```

As SO is to learn from each other please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read about `Private Members in JavaScript` by **Douglas Crockford** [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) which explains `private` and `public` varibles in JavaScript and will explain you why your function `Option1` and `Option2` are behaving so.

Comment: That article is useful, but I'm either failing somewhere, or he has some unclear bit at the end. Patterns -> private -> you can't reach `membername`, and he uses it as both `var` & `function`??

Comment: @Noctis He means those are different ways of creating `private` members.